# How do I provide an implementation of fetch Headers in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Specifically, I am using a 3rd party library which has the following property on an interface:

```
readonly Headers: typeof Headers;
```

Where of course headers is:

```
var Headers: {
new (init?: HeadersInit | undefined): Headers;
prototype: Headers; }
```

I am struggling to understand what this is trying to tell me. As far as I can tell the interface is expecting an instance of Headers but it complains:

```
Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'Headers' but required in type '{ new (init?: HeadersInit | undefined): Headers; prototype: Headers; }'.ts(2741)
```

Is this trying to tell me that instead of passing an object it is expecting a type which it can later instantiate? If so then how do I create a type to handle this?

What I am trying to do is so simple, just want to be able to supply a Header with Authorization but I do not get what it expects!

Any sample would be much appreciated :)

Comment: What's the URL to the library's source code? Based _only_ on what you've provided, it seems like the property has been mis-typed (wanting the constructor, rather than an instance), but without seeing the type in context, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: @jsejcksn The url is https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/master/packages/services/src/serverconnection.ts and the function I am calling is ServerConnection.makeSettings, trying to provide my own headers via the Headers property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you've provided, you need to supply the `Headers` constructor:

```ts
{ Headers: Headers }
```

rather than an instance:

```ts
{ Headers: new Headers() }
```

---

The [JSDoc comment](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/136764f58c2ea7041a49584162b41a48db329bb3/packages/services/src/serverconnection.ts#L96-L99) clarifies this:

```ts
    /**
     * The `Headers` object constructor.
     */
    readonly Headers: typeof Headers;
```

and the [README](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/tree/136764f58c2ea7041a49584162b41a48db329bb3/packages/services#jupyterlab-services) also clarifies this:

> Note: All functions and classes using the REST API allow a `serverSettings`
> parameter to configure requests.
> Requests are made using the `fetch` API, which is available in modern browsers
> or via `npm install fetch` for node users. The `whatwg-fetch` npm package
> can be used to polyfill browsers that do not support the `fetch` API.

---

Although you left out what seems to be your real question, I think you want to know how to use this package: install `node-fetch` first, then use the `ServerConnection.makeSettings()` method, which will [generate the (default) settings](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/136764f58c2ea7041a49584162b41a48db329bb3/packages/services/src/serverconnection.ts#L16-L24) you need, and create your request init using the `Headers` class from `node-fetch`:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwBIFMCGATFUDOBfOAMyghDgHIA7CLAWkJRgGMALcgbgFgAoUSWRAGVsAN2wBhCJUoomMYFILFSFAAIArAK5gAnjGwAbNACMA9DlHAmKHBx48mUnPAsx5lAOY44AXjjCoMShJaVl5KQA6EDQAaxRhN2BPHAAKAEoubh4AoJCZOQVKKNiUACUUAEdNGxgUnjgKFjcwHAAuU1NNKAMIlAAPNHADFHIAGnrECYaWdCxcVrgZAHc4VExsVIBtKYa4TfIdCC6AfRn13DGKDwhT7BGAXXHuXbh7tKeGvA+4V3cvJ4yQA)

```ts
import {Headers} from 'node-fetch';
import {ServerConnection} from '@jupyterlab/services';

const settings = ServerConnection.makeSettings();

ServerConnection.makeRequest(
  'https://url.example',
  {
    headers: new Headers([
      ['your_headers', 'go_here'],
    ]),
  },
  settings,
);
```

Comment: Yes, but if I do that then when do I get a chance to add my own headers? Seems like in that scenario the library instantiates an instance and I never get a chance to do anything with it, which makes no sense

Comment: I share your sentiment. It seems like a bizarre pattern without knowing more about the library. Perhaps there is a place where you are offered a headers instance and you can use its methods to manipulate it?

Comment: I see your edit and I read that as well but as we have discussed it makes no logical sense, what is the point of providing a Headers constructor if you can never modify it. Unless you can provide an override of Headers, but not sure how to do that given its just a var

Comment: Ah, I see now. This is definitely an interface for supplying constructors. It appears that the package is designed to be used in different contexts where those types might not be available in the global scope (or to give the consumer the opportunity to customize which ones are used for constructing values).

Comment: @user1371314 See the information in my updated answer

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive answer @jsejcksn. And indeed that would work except I left out perhaps the most important piece of information. I am constructing the settings object to pass to the constructor on the managers (e.g KernelManager). It is those managers that make the requests, so it seems I would need to pass in a fully constituted settings here for that to work

Comment: So you’re saying you tried creating the settings using `makeSettings` and that it didn’t work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242387/discussion-between-user1371314-and-jsejcksn).